# stdarg и что здесь вообще происходит?

Tags: c, visual-c++

Написал простейший код с использованием varidatic functions

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

typedef void (*callback_ft)();

void OnPlayerJoin(int, char*);
void OnPlayerDisconnect(int, char*, int);


void call(callback_ft callback, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, callback);
    callback(args);
    va_end(args);
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    call(OnPlayerJoin, "Mike");
    call(OnPlayerJoin, "Bob", "Hello"); // неправильный вызов
    call(OnPlayerDisconnect, "John", 176);
    call(OnPlayerDisconnect, "John"); // неправильный вызов
}

void OnPlayerJoin(int n, char* name) { printf("Hi %s!\n", name); }
void OnPlayerDisconnect(int n, char* name, int time) { printf("%s disconnected! Played for %imin\n", name, time); }
```

Код работает, запускается и выводит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но у меня возникло 3 вопроса:

1. Почему при указании сигнатуры функции с пустыми параметрами, в вызываемые аргументы передаются правильно, даже с учётом того, что первый опорный параметр **n** явно не передаётся?
2. Почему при неправильном вызове код продолжает более-менее адекватно работать не вываливаясь сразу в segfault?
3. Насколько такой код переносим и насколько его опасно применять в реальных проектах?

Я действительно не понимаю как это работает и почему это вообще работает...

[Visual Studio 2022 | Стандартные настройки проекта, кроме флагов /TC и /std:c17]

Comment: Потому что собирали как 64-разрядное приложение. Попробуйте сделать то же в 32-разрядном :) Вот вам и ответ о переносимости и т.д....

Comment: @Harry , и правда в выводе появляется дуристика. Но она всё равно появляется, не выпадая в ошибку (возможно до поры, до времени).
Провёл тесты на OnlineGDB и на компиляторе в телефоне - всё так же кроме 2ого параметра - 176 - он не передаётся.

Comment: На то и UB... Значит, указатель в памяти оказывается не из тех, что программу валят. UB — это ж как на красный свет перебегать: совсем не обязательно вас при этом сразу же собьют, а то, что не собьют, совсем не значит, что так можно делать :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Тип `typedef void (*callback_ft)();` означает указатель на функцию с аргументом типа `void` или `int`. Но никак не `va_list`
   Неправильное использование функции приводит к неопределённому поведению. **UB**
2. ... **UB**
3. Никак не переносим.

Переносимым будет если вы передадите функциям указатель на список аргументов. И не надеяться на  удачу.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

typedef void (*callback_ft)(va_list*);

// int n , char * name
void OnPlayerJoin(va_list*);
// int n , char * name , int time
void OnPlayerDisconnect(va_list*);

void call(callback_ft callback, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, callback);
    callback(&args);
    va_end(args);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    call(OnPlayerJoin, (int)0,(char*)"Mike");
    call(OnPlayerJoin, (int)1,(char*)"Bob");
    call(OnPlayerDisconnect,(int)0,(char*)"John", (int)176);
    call(OnPlayerDisconnect, (int)1,(char*)"John",(int)5);
}

void OnPlayerJoin(va_list*const l) {
 int n = va_arg(*l, int);
 char* name = va_arg(*l, char*);     
 printf("Hi %s!\n", name); 
}

void OnPlayerDisconnect(va_list*const l) {
 int n = va_arg(*l, int);
 char* name = va_arg(*l, char*);  
 int time = va_arg(*l, int);  
 printf("%s disconnected! Played for %imin\n",
  name, time); 
}
```

Comment: А возможно ли сделать так, чтобы если callback не описан - он ничего в коде не делал, а если описан где-то уже вызывалась нужная ф-ия?
Например есть сигнатура той-же `void OnPlayerJoin()`
Он используется в коде и вызывается из других частей программы.
но если нету семантики `OnPlayerJoin() {...}` то сама сигнатура ничего не делает, а если есть, то выполняется тело `OnPlayerJoin`
Если я правильно нужно будет воспользоваться макросами, но я не могу допереть до этого)

Comment: ничего не понял, наверное вы можете кидать в функцию указатель. А указатель будет указывать на нужную функцию или **NULL**. Так что-ли? `callback_ft PointerToFunction = NULL ; PointerToFunction = OnPlayerJoin ; if ( PointerToFunction ) call(PointerToFunction, (int)0,(char*)"Mike");`

Comment: Нуууу, я бы посоветовал просто заменить call, на макрос :)

Comment: Макросы и функциональное программирование не срастутся. @ori

Comment: Ну макрос ограничит вызов если там параметров больше чем необходимо

Comment: В примере как раз и вызываются разное количество аргументов 2 или 3. @ori совет не очень.

Comment: `#define call(CALLBACK, ...) CALLBACK(__VA_ARGS__)` :) @AlexGlebe [Пример](https://onlinegdb.com/1kIknW7wh)

Comment: Не совсем. Условно `OnPlayerJoin` описан, не определён в коде. Но как только мы его определяем вручную `void OnPlayerJoin() { MakeSome1(); MakeSome2(); }` То он уже начинает вызываться нормально. То есть что-то вроде перегрузки. Пока не определили, используется "пустая" реализация, когда определили используется наша. Возможно я немного не правильно объясняю но видел такой механизм в языке PAWN, где мы, если вручную описываем како-то вызов, задействуется наш, иначе просто ничего не происходит. Проблема в том, что я получаю ошибку линковщика, если пытаюсь оставить сигнатуру без определения.

Comment: Если вы объявили декларацию функции, поменять её уже нельзя. Можно только сделать глобальный указатель. Который как раз и можно поменять. Как я и предлагал.